# Eclipse Open CV Application building error?

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I am going to build my Open CV project(C++) in Eclipse, but it gives an error in **makefile**, the error is

```
        recipe for target `Open_CV.exe' failed
```

i have also included the lib and opencv in project successfuly, but i don't know why i am getting this error, sometimes i am also getting an error in its **subdir** file

and Error log is :

Build of configuration Debug for project Open_CV **

make all 
Building file: ../src/Open_CV.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -I"C:\OpenCV2.0\include\opencv" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Open_CV.d" -MT"src/Open_CV.d" -o"src/Open_CV.o" "../src/Open_CV.c"
In file included from C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:1612,
                 from ../src/Open_CV.c:8:
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h: In function `cvMinAreaRect':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:425: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:425: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:425: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:425: warning: statement with no effect
../src/Open_CV.c: In function`main':
../src/Open_CV.c:20: warning: implicit declaration of function `printf'
../src/Open_CV.c: At top level:
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:249: warning: 'cvFloor' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:267: warning: 'cvCeil' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:287: warning: 'cvIsNaN' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:302: warning: 'cvIsInf' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:321: warning: 'cvRNG' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:337: warning: 'cvRandReal' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:670: warning: 'cvmGet' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:705: warning: 'cvIplDepth' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:880: warning: 'cvRectToROI' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:893: warning: 'cvROIToRect' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:914: warning: 'cvTermCriteria' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:936: warning: 'cvPoint' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:966: warning: 'cvPointTo32f' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:991: warning: 'cvPoint3D32f' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:1011: warning: 'cvPoint2D64f' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:1031: warning: 'cvPoint3D64f' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:1052: warning: 'cvSize' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:1070: warning: 'cvSize2D32f' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:1146: warning: 'cvRealScalar' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:1154: warning: 'cvScalarAll' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxtypes.h:1666: warning: 'cvAttrList' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:153: warning: 'cvDecRefData' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:174: warning: 'cvIncRefData' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:208: warning: 'cvGetRow' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:219: warning: 'cvGetCol' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:248: warning: 'cvReleaseMatND' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:271: warning: 'cvGetNextSparseNode' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:522: warning: 'cvSubS' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1083: warning: 'cvCloneSeq' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1126: warning: 'cvSetNew' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1141: warning: 'cvSetRemoveByPtr' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1156: warning: 'cvGetSetElem' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1323: warning: 'cvEllipseBox' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1414: warning: 'cvFont' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1672: warning: 'cvReadIntByName' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1687: warning: 'cvReadRealByName' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1701: warning: 'cvReadStringByName' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1713: warning: 'cvReadByName' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmisc.h:222: warning: 'cvAlignPtr' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmisc.h:228: warning: 'cvAlign' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmisc.h:234: warning: 'cvGetMatSize' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:635: warning: 'cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:670: warning: 'cvSubdiv2DNextEdge' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:676: warning: 'cvSubdiv2DRotateEdge' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:681: warning: 'cvSubdiv2DSymEdge' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:686: warning: 'cvSubdiv2DGetEdge' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:694: warning: 'cvSubdiv2DEdgeOrg' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:701: warning: 'cvSubdiv2DEdgeDst' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:708: warning: 'cvTriangleArea' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:892: warning: 'cvCalcHist' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:1136: warning: 'cvSURFPoint' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:1207: warning: 'cvStarKeypoint' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cv.h:1231: warning: 'cvStarDetectorParams' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:112: warning: 'cvMatArray' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:127: warning: 'cvMean' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:134: warning: 'cvSumPixels' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:141: warning: 'cvMean_StdDev' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:154: warning: 'cvmPerspectiveProject' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:165: warning: 'cvFillImage' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:216: warning: 'cvRandInit' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:249: warning: 'cvbRand' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:257: warning: 'cvbCartToPolar' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:273: warning: 'cvbFastArctan' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:286: warning: 'cvbSqrt' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:296: warning: 'cvbInvSqrt' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:306: warning: 'cvbReciprocal' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:316: warning: 'cvbFastExp' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:324: warning: 'cvbFastLog' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:332: warning: 'cvContourBoundingRect' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:338: warning: 'cvPseudoInverse' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:385: warning: 'cvConvexHull' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:413: warning: 'cvMinAreaRect' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:434: warning: 'cvFitLine3D' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:444: warning: 'cvFitLine2D' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:453: warning: 'cvFitEllipse' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:464: warning: 'cvProject3D' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:506: warning: 'cvHoughLines' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:519: warning: 'cvHoughLinesP' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:531: warning: 'cvHoughLinesSDiv' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:543: warning: 'cvFindFundamentalMatrix' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:577: warning: 'cvFindChessBoardCornerGuesses' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:588: warning: 'cvCalibrateCamera' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:613: warning: 'cvCalibrateCamera_64d' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:642: warning: 'cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:667: warning: 'cvFindExtrinsicCameraParams_64d' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:693: warning: 'cvRodrigues' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:711: warning: 'cvProjectPoints' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:740: warning: 'cvProjectPointsSimple' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:771: warning: 'cvUnDistortInit' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:786: warning: 'cvUnDistort' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:804: warning: 'cvCalcEMD' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:815: warning: 'cvKMeans' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:829: warning: 'cvStartScanGraph' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:842: warning: 'cvEndScanGraph' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:862: warning: 'cvLineAA' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:868: warning: 'cvCircleAA' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:876: warning: 'cvEllipseAA' defined but not used
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:883: warning: 'cvPolyLineAA' defined but not used
Finished building: ../src/Open_CV.c

Building target: Open_CV.exe
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
gcc -L"C:\OpenCV2.0\lib" -o"Open_CV.exe"  ./src/Open_CV.o   -lcv200 -lhighgui200
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvDecRefData':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:159: undefined reference to`*cvFree*'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:167: undefined reference to `_cvFree_'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvGetRow':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:209: undefined reference to `_cvGetRows'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvGetCol':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:220: undefined reference to `_cvGetCols'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvReleaseMatND':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:249: undefined reference to `_cvReleaseMat'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvSubS':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:523: undefined reference to `_cvAddS'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvCloneSeq':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1084: undefined reference to `_cvSeqSlice'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvSetNew':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1135: undefined reference to `_cvSetAdd'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvGetSetElem':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1157: undefined reference to `_cvGetSeqElem'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvEllipseBox':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1328: undefined reference to `_cvEllipse'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvFont':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1416: undefined reference to `_cvInitFont'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvReadIntByName':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1673: undefined reference to `_cvGetFileNodeByName'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvReadRealByName':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1688: undefined reference to `_cvGetFileNodeByName'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvReadStringByName':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1702: undefined reference to `_cvGetFileNodeByName'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvReadByName':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1714: undefined reference to `_cvGetFileNodeByName'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1714: undefined reference to`_cvRead'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvMean':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:128: undefined reference to`_cvAvg'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvSumPixels':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:135: undefined reference to`_cvSum'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvMean_StdDev':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:143: undefined reference to`_cvAvgSdv'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvmPerspectiveProject':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:157: undefined reference to`_cvReshape'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:158: undefined reference to `_cvReshape'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:160: undefined reference to`_cvPerspectiveTransform'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvFillImage':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:166: undefined reference to`_cvGetElemType'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:166: undefined reference to `_cvColorToScalar'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:166: undefined reference to`_cvSet'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvRandSetRange':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:188: undefined reference to`_cvError'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:194: undefined reference to `_cvError'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvRandInit':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:219: undefined reference to `_cvError'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:225: undefined reference to`_cvError'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvRand':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:240: undefined reference to`_cvError'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:243: undefined reference to `_cvRandArr'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvbCartToPolar':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:267: undefined reference to `_cvCartToPolar'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvbFastArctan':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:281: undefined reference to `_cvCartToPolar'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvbSqrt':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:291: undefined reference to `_cvPow'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvbInvSqrt':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:301: undefined reference to `_cvPow'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvbReciprocal':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:311: undefined reference to `_cvPow'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvbFastExp':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:319: undefined reference to `_cvExp'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvbFastLog':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:327: undefined reference to `_cvLog'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvPseudoInverse':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:339: undefined reference to `_cvInvert'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvProject3D':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:473: undefined reference to `_cvTransform'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvFindFundamentalMatrix':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:549: undefined reference to `_cvCreateMat'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:550: undefined reference to`_cvCreateMat'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:566: undefined reference to `_cvReleaseMat'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:567: undefined reference to`_cvReleaseMat'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvUnDistortInit':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:774: undefined reference to`_cvGetRawData'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvUnDistort':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:790: undefined reference to`_cvGetRawData'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvKMeans':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:816: undefined reference to`_cvCreateMat'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:821: undefined reference to `_cvKMeans2'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:822: undefined reference to`_cvReleaseMat'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvStartScanGraph':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:833: undefined reference to`_cvError'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:835: undefined reference to `_cvCreateGraphScanner'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:837: undefined reference to`*cvFree*'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvEndScanGraph':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:844: undefined reference to`_cvError'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:848: undefined reference to `_cvAlloc'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:850: undefined reference to`_cvReleaseGraphScanner'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvLineAA':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:863: undefined reference to`_cvGetElemType'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:863: undefined reference to `_cvColorToScalar'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:863: undefined reference to`_cvLine'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvCircleAA':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:869: undefined reference to`_cvGetElemType'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:869: undefined reference to `_cvColorToScalar'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:869: undefined reference to`_cvCircle'
./src/Open_CV.o: In function `cvEllipseAA':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:877: undefined reference to`_cvGetElemType'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:877: undefined reference to `_cvColorToScalar'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:877: undefined reference to`_cvEllipse'
makefile:30: recipe for target `Open_CV.exe' failed
./src/Open_CV.o: In function`cvPolyLineAA':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:884: undefined reference to `_cvGetElemType'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:884: undefined reference to`_cvColorToScalar'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cvcompat.h:884: undefined reference to `_cvPolyLine'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Open_CV.exe] Error 1

Comment: can you post the full error log? This pretty much only says "there is something wrong"

Comment: @example yeah, wait i am going to upload now...

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to link the libcxcore "-lcxcore" (or maybe "-lcvaux").

Comment: How can i include it, please help